# file select button, how to unselect a file?

Tags: upload, webpage, homepage

Some homepages allow you to upload documents. There is a button "choose file" and then you choose a file. After everything is ready you hit a button "upload" or "continue" the documents are uploaded after hitting the button.

Now I just came across such a webpage. Some things have to be entered, after that a few upload buttons. I choose some files, did not upload them yet, I did not click on "continue" yet.

Now the files are selected. How can I delete one of the files? There is no button to undo a select file, the file is selected and stays selected.

How can I unselect a file so it gets not uploaded when hitting "continue"?

Note: I do not want to reload the page.

Comment: press Ctrl and click on one of the file. let me know if that help

Answer (score 1):

According to this : https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/257485
you can't perform it with Firefox and Safari.
If you're using Google Chrome or IE, try clear the text field.

Note:
It might be a security problem if the field is editable. If some JS code replaces your path file with an other when you submit the form, the website could upload any file from your computer.

Comment: Tried with IE, clearing text field does not work. File is still selected and uploaded, but text field is empty.

Comment: So I think that's not possible without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  <kbd>**Ctrl+Arrow**</kbd>  to move among selected items.  <kbd>**Ctrl+Space**</kbd>  will select/deselect.

Comment: Its not a file selection, but a complete deselection: http://abload.de/img/1mboyb.png

Comment: @kelmat can share the link for the site?

Answer (score 0):

A descent web interface will have a remove butten per row on the selected files. Or a selection box with an action chooser where you should be able to choose remove or delete.

If you just are in the OS file chooser dialog you can select a file range using the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and remove single files from the selection using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> per file you want to remove from the selection.

Comment: Its not a file selection, but a complete deselection: http://abload.de/img/1mboyb.png